# Options to wipe stack memory before function return

Tags: c, security, stack

When writing `c` code that deals with sensitive data I heard that an attacker could could attempt to read memory left in the stack after a function that handles sensitive data returns. It seems a painstaking process to zero all the stack memory before a function returns. Also it requires using `-O0` to ensure the compiler doesn't optimize away the zeroing code. Is there any way to automatically wipe stack memory? Maybe compiler flags, defines, or perhaps an assembly language inline function that reads stack size and zeros it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way (*that I know of*) to do it portably.

What you could do (and should work) is simply call another function with a stack-allocated array, large enough to cover the sensitive area of the previous call.

After that, `memset` said array in the function. It might be a good idea to declare the array as `volatile`, so that the `memset` doesn't get optimized away.

Example for C99 (because it uses variable-length arrays):

```
void clear_stack(size_t sz)
{
    // you can try using `alloca` or a fixed-size array if not using C99
    // make sure `sz` is small enough to avoid stack overflows
    volatile char arr[sz];
    memset(arr, 0, sz);
}
```

Comment: the stack, when in a function contains (calling parameters in reverse order, callers PC register for the instruction after the call statement, the called functions auto variables, in reverse order.   Due to the above, about the best that can be done is for the called function to set each of the passed parameters and auto variables to 0

Comment: Not a bad idea, it requires the caller to remember to call the clear_stack function after each security related function. To mitigate the problem we could make these sensitive functions `static` and then expose secure versions that call the sensitive function immediately followed by the clear stack function. Then only function calls in the same file need to be careful.

Comment: @satur9nine: Indeed, that's one good way to do it. I was just describing the memory-cleaning, not how it would be *used*. Of course, this isn't entirely portable *in principle* (since the machine might not have a stack at all), but should be *in practice*. If security is truly essential, this code (any, really - but *especially* this code) should be audited on/for each individual system. In some systems, you have dedicated functions that you can use instead of `memset` (e.g. [`SecureZeroMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use stack vars? Could you use heap vars instead and control the memory that way?

You could allocate a large enough chunk of heap memory and assign typed pointers into it for vars, then just memset it to zero before freeing the block.

Comment: That may make the application significantly slower. Additionally, it is possible that the function descends into calls which themselves make use of the stack; so this would require that all possible functions dealing with sensitive data will not use the stack

Comment: Using the stack is pretty convenient, but yes it is much easier to wipe areas of the wipe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a completely portable solution. I had attempted to answer this before with a generic solution but realized that local variable reorganization by the compiler makes it pretty much impossible to zero the stack of the function currently being executed.

However I did find a solution to zero stack memory after a function returns although it is dependent on support from the operating system. In this case FreeRTOS, though I'm sure it could be adapted to other simple RTOS's. This solution is a bit like Tim Čas' suggestion but rather than hoping to cover over memory with an appropriate sized array it wipes everything because it knows exactly where the stack is.

Add the following code to `task.c`:

```
void *pvGetCurrentTaskStackStart(void) {
    return (void *)pxCurrentTCB->pxStack;
}
```

Here is a function to wipe all the unused (but dirty) memory on the stack for the current task:

```
void wipe_task_stack(void)
{
    int i;
    register uint32_t sp asm ("sp");
    uint32_t stack_start = (uint32_t) pvGetCurrentTaskStackStart();
    uint32_t size = sp - stack_start;

    /* Do not use memset or similar function, it would wipe its own stack! */
    for (i = i; i < size; i++) {
        ((volatile uint8_t *) stack_start)[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here are some nice articles about why zeroing memory is hard:

http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-04-how-to-zero-a-buffer.html

http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-05-erratum.html

http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-06-zeroing-buffers-is-insufficient.html